# How to get Age using BirthDate column by MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, date

I have a BirthDate column in MySQL database table to store user's date of birth. Now I have form in html/php with two fields(1. Age From 2. Age To).

If user want to get all users where their ages are between 10 years and 20 years, Is it possible to do this with MySQL query using BirthDate column.

Thanks

Comment: What's the data type of the BirthDate column?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your query would look similar to this:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(BirthDate) BETWEEN 10 AND 20;
```

Comment: Its looking simple and perfect.

Comment: @soulkphp It does not work for people whose birthdate is after the current date. For example, if someone was born on 1986-11-30, he would have 25 years old, not 26 as your query would compute it.

Comment: @RomainGuidoux I made the wild assumption that people can't be born in the future :)

Comment: Old question, I know, but I think what @RomainGuidoux meant was that if you were specifically looking for someone who was 9 years old, this would be (currently) 2015 - 2006.  But that will also get you someone who is 8 years old if they were born later in the year.  So if this is April, and they were born in September, they will still show up even though they are only 8 years old.

Comment: This not working if my date type varchar "March 1, 1990"??

Answer (score 8):

You can get like this

```
SELECT column1, column2, 
   DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(now()) - TO_DAYS(dob)), '%Y') + 0 as age     
WHERE age >10 AND age <20 ;
```

Comment: This should be the selected answer.  This gets the age right down to the day as apposed to just the year.

Answer (score 5):

```
select * from table where
(year(curdate())-year(dob))-(right(curdate(),5)< right(dob,5) )
between 10 and 20
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution which checks the year and the month:

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE FLOOR(DATEDIFF(curdate(), birthdate) / 365.25) BETWEEN 10 AND 20
```

Answer (score 0):

It can also be achived by using a sub query:

```
select *
    from (select *, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, birthday, NOW()) as age from table_name) as sub_query
    where age between 10 AND 20
```