# How to get Age in Months using BirthDate column by MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime

*First I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591582/how-to-get-age-using-birthdate-column-by-mysql-query) to do this and accepted answer helped me. But Now the problem is that I have to calculate age in months.*

**Question:**

I have a BirthDate column in MySQL database table to store user's date of birth. Now I have form in html/php with two fields(1. Age From 2. Age To).

If user want to get all users where their ages are between 400 months and 600 months, Is it possible to do this with MySQL query using BirthDate column.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select * from [table] 
where 
BirthDate>= date_sub(curdate(),interval 600 MONTH)
and 
BirthDate<= date_sub(curdate(),interval 400 MONTH)
```

Comment: or `where BirthDate between date_sub(...) and date_sub(...)`

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM that_table
WHERE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP BETWEEN (BirthDate + INTERVAL 400 MONTH) AND (BirthDate + INTERVAL 600 MONTH)
```